# When to use "ON UPDATE CASCADE"

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I use `ON DELETE CASCADE` regularly but I never use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` as I am not so sure in what situation it will be useful.

For the sake of discussion let see some code.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

For `ON DELETE CASCADE`, if a parent with an `id` is deleted, a record in child with `parent_id = parent.id` will be automatically deleted. This should be no problem.

1. This means that `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will do the same thing when `id` of the parent is updated?
2. If (1) is true, it means that there is no need to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` if `parent.id` is not updatable (or will never be updated) like when it is `AUTO_INCREMENT` or always set to be `TIMESTAMP`. Is that right?
3. If (2) is not true, in what other kind of situation should we use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`?
4. What if I (for some reason) update the `child.parent_id` to be something not existing, will it then be automatically deleted?

Well, I know, some of the question above can be test programmatically to understand but I want also know if any of this is database vendor dependent or not.

Please shed some light.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894162/postgresql-how-to-compact-renumber-id-for-all-tables-and-reset-sequences-to-max

Answer (score 609, accepted):

It's true that if your primary key is just an identity value auto incremented, you would have no real use for `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

However, let's say that your primary key is a 10 digit UPC bar code and because of expansion, you need to change it to a 13-digit UPC bar code.  In that case, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` would allow you to change the primary key value and any tables that have foreign key references to the value will be changed accordingly.

In reference to #4, if you change the child ID to something that doesn't exist in the parent table (and you have referential integrity), you should get a foreign key error.

Comment: Just had to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` myself to update primary keys in an old table which does not use an auto-incremented key

Comment: When you soft delete a user from your database (eg. unregister the user but keep its anonymized data for historical statistics) you likely want to also anonymize its ID (eg. regenerate one) so that you minimize ways of finding its profile again (its ID could be found in old logs somewhere, previous emails...)

Answer (score 123):

1. Yes, it means that for example if you do `UPDATE parent SET id = 20 WHERE id = 10` all children parent_id's of 10 will also be updated to 20
2. If you don't update the field the foreign key refers to, this setting is not needed
3. Can't think of any other use.
4. You can't do that as the foreign key constraint would fail.

Answer (score 37):

I think you've pretty much nailed the points!

If you follow database design best practices and your primary key is never updatable (which I think should always be the case anyway), then you never really need the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause.

**Zed** made a good point, that if you use a **natural** key (e.g. a regular field from your database table) as your primary key, then there might be certain situations where you need to update your primary keys. Another recent example would be the ISBN (International Standard Book Numbers) which changed from 10 to 13 digits+characters not too long ago.

This is not the case if you choose to use **surrogate** (e.g. artifically system-generated) keys as your primary key (which would be my preferred choice in all but the most rare occasions).

So in the end: if your primary key never changes, then you never need the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause.

Marc

Comment: What is "artificially system-generated" keys? UUIDs?

Comment: @HPWD: just an "artificial" key (a value that is not based on or derived from your actual data) which is generated by the system - it *can be* a GUID, or an INT, or a BIGINT - or anything really - doesn't matter. Point is: that value is in no way related to your own, actual data - and the system is generating that value automatically for you.

Comment: @marc-s thank you for taking the time to write that out. Your answer made perfect sense.

Comment: A single-column table with natural keys is a good & clean alternative to enums in my opinion (at least in MySQL DB flavors). For example, consider a table `colors` with rows `blue`, `purple`, `yellow`, and a table `products` with a `product_color` column, being FK'ed to the `colors` table. That restricts the choices like an enum, but unlike an auto-incrementing integer it doesn't require a join to get the color name. In such a case, `on update cascade` is a good idea, if you decide that `purple` should be called `violet` instead.

Answer (score 22):

A few days ago I've had an issue with triggers, and I've figured out that `ON UPDATE CASCADE` can be useful. Take a look at this example (PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE club
(
    key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE band
(
    key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE concert
(
    key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    club_name TEXT REFERENCES club(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    band_name TEXT REFERENCES band(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    concert_date DATE
);
```

In my issue, I had to define some additional operations (trigger) for updating the concert's table. Those operations had to modify club_name and band_name. I was unable to do it, because of reference. I couldn't modify concert and then deal with club and band tables. I couldn't also do it the other way. `ON UPDATE CASCADE` was the key to solve the problem.

Comment: Good comment. I find on update cascade also useful, in any case you have to change your ID. I also agree with others that this change should not so typical. For example, in the case you quote, I think that in big volumes of data, perhaps relating foreign keys using text fields might not result in the fastest performance of the database engine. Observe, that if the foreign relation in the concert table uses club.SERIAL and the band.SERIAL, the changes in the name wouldn't affect the relation between the tables. However, I find ON UPDATE CASCADE is a great tool for solving emergencies. Regards

Comment: This is a questionable design which makes for a rather contrived example, though. What's the point of keeping two `SERIAL` columns in `club` and `band` as primary keys if you reference `name`s instead of each table's primary key?

Comment: In short, this is useful if you're duplicating field from other table and you need it to be up to date.

Answer (score 10):

The `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` specify which action will execute when a row in the parent table is updated and deleted. The following are permitted actions : `NO ACTION`, `CASCADE`, `SET NULL`, and `SET DEFAULT`.

#### Delete actions of rows in the parent table

If you delete one or more rows in the parent table, you can set one of the following actions:

- `ON DELETE NO ACTION`: SQL Server raises an error and rolls back the delete action on the row in the parent table.
- `ON DELETE CASCADE`: SQL Server deletes the rows in the child table that is corresponding to the row deleted from the parent table.
- `ON DELETE SET NULL`: SQL Server sets the rows in the child table to NULL if the corresponding rows in the parent table are deleted. To execute this action, the foreign key columns must be nullable.
- `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`: SQL Server sets the rows in the child table to their default values if the corresponding rows in the parent table are deleted. To execute this action, the foreign key columns must have default definitions. Note that a nullable column has a default value of NULL if no default value specified.
  By default, SQL Server appliesON DELETE NO ACTION if you don’t explicitly specify any action.

#### Update action of rows in the parent table

If you update one or more rows in the parent table, you can set one of the following actions:

- `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`: SQL Server raises an error and rolls back the update action on the row in the parent table.
- `ON UPDATE CASCADE`: SQL Server updates the corresponding rows in the child table when the rows in the parent table are updated.
- `ON UPDATE SET NULL`: SQL Server sets the rows in the child table to NULL when the corresponding row in the parent table is updated. Note that the foreign key columns must be nullable for this action to execute.
- `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT`: SQL Server sets the default values for the rows in the child table that have the corresponding rows in the parent table updated.

```sql
FOREIGN KEY (foreign_key_columns)
    REFERENCES parent_table(parent_key_columns)
    ON UPDATE <action> 
    ON DELETE <action>;
```

See [the reference tutorial](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-foreign-key/).

Comment: Major nitpick: This entry doesn't answer the OP's question which was about **when** to use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, a kind of "best-practice" question. You just copied what's in the reference tutorial.

Comment: Minor nitpick: there are relational DB systems other than SQL Server, you know. Such as MySQL, Postgres, ... etc. The `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` options on FKs are pretty much standard across major DB-s.

Answer (score 6):

It's an excellent question, I had the same question yesterday. I thought about this problem, specifically SEARCHED if existed something like "ON UPDATE CASCADE" and fortunately the designers of SQL had also thought about that. I agree with Ted.strauss,  and I also commented Noran's case.

When did I use it? Like Ted pointed out, when you are treating several databases at one time, and the modification in one of them, in one table, has any kind of reproduction in what Ted calls "satellite database", can't be kept with the very original ID, and for any reason you have to create a new one, in case you can't update the data on the old one (for example due to permissions, or in case you are searching for fastness in a case that is so ephemeral that doesn't deserve the absolute and utter respect for the total rules of normalization, simply because will be a very short-lived utility)

So, I agree in two points:

(A.) Yes, in many times a better design can avoid it; BUT

(B.) In cases of migrations, replicating databases, or solving emergencies, it's a GREAT TOOL that fortunately was there when I went to search if it existed.

Answer (score 4):

My comment is mainly in reference to point #3: under what circumstances is ON UPDATE CASCADE applicable if we're assuming that the parent key is not updateable? Here is one case.

I am dealing with a replication scenario in which multiple satellite databases need to be merged with a master. Each satellite is generating data on the same tables, so merging of the tables to the master leads to violations of the uniqueness constraint. I'm trying to use ON UPDATE CASCADE as part of a solution in which I re-increment the keys during each merge. ON UPDATE CASCADE should simplify this process by automating part of the process.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other great answers here it is important to use ON UPDATE CASCADE (or on DELETE CASCADE...) cautiously. Operations on tables with this specification require exclusive lock on underlaying relations.

If you have multiple CASCADE definitions in one table (as in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14238129/3043837)), and especially multiple tables using same definitions, and multiple users updating, this can create a deadlock when one process acquires exclusive lock on first underlaying table, other exclusive lock on second, and they block out each other by none of them being able to get both (all) exclusive locks to perform operation.