# Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, postgresql-9.1

At what point is a `DEFERRED` / `DEFERRABLE`/ `IMMEDIATE` unique / primary key constraint enforced exactly?
I am asking in connection  with [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032028/939860).

Tried with this testbed in PostgreSQL 9.1.2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  id  integer
, txt text
, CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES
  (1, 'one')
, (2, 'two')
;
```

#### 1) `UPDATE` statement modifying multiple rows:

```
UPDATE tbl t
SET    id = t_old.id
FROM   tbl t_old
WHERE (t.id, t_old.id) IN ((1,2), (2,1));
```

The above `UPDATE` works, though I expected it to fail. The constraint is defined `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` and no `SET CONSTRAINTS` was issued.
What am I missing?

#### 2) Data modifying CTE

A data modifying CTE works the same. Though either fails with a `NOT DEFERRED` PK:

```sql
WITH upd1 AS (
   UPDATE tbl
   SET    id = 1
   WHERE  id = 2
   )
UPDATE tbl
SET    id = 2
WHERE  id = 1;
```

[The manual on CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other
> and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying
> statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates
> actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with
> the same *snapshot* (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot "see" each
> others' effects on the target tables.

#### 3) Multiple `UPDATE` statements in one transaction

Without `SET CONSTRAINTS`, this fails with a UNIQUE violation - as expected:

```sql
BEGIN;
-- SET CONSTRAINTS t_pkey DEFERRED;
UPDATE tbl SET id = 2 WHERE txt = 'one';
UPDATE tbl SET id = 1 WHERE txt = 'two';
COMMIT;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bd6aWtp7)

Comment: Same with 9.1.3 on Windows. You should report that as a bug to the PostgreSQL team.

Comment: The way I read the documentation, I think the update should fail. I'd call it a bug.

Comment: Can you refer to the documentation that shows why "The above UPDATE works though it should not." - why that update should not work?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov: Look at the answers below. Also follow [the link in the comments](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/519FAC78.7090603@falter.at) and consider Peter Eisentraut's answer there.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter which says "The SQL standard says that uniqueness should be enforced only at the end of the statement ... To obtain standard-compliant behavior, declare the constraint as DEFERRABLE but not deferred (i.e., INITIALLY IMMEDIATE)" - this is exactly what you are doing, so your update should succeed, because at the end of the statement all IDs are unique.

Comment: I was surprised to see the famous Erwin Brandstetter asking a question rather than answering it, then I saw that it was 8 years ago and was only confusing due to a bug in Postgres at the time, and it all adds up.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I remember having raised an almost identical point when PG9 was in alpha state. Here was the answer from Tom Lane (high-profile PG core developer):
http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2010-01/msg00221.php

In short: won't fix.

Not to say that I agree with your suggestion that the current behavior is a bug. Look at it from the opposite angle: it's the behavior of `NOT DEFERRABLE` that is incorrect.

In fact, the constraint violation in this UPDATE should never happen in any case, since at the end of the UPDATE the constraint is satisfied. The state at the end of the command is what matters. The intermediate states during the execution of a single statement should not be exposed to the user.

It seems like the PostgreSQL implements the non deferrable constraint by checking for duplicates after every row updated and failing immediately upon the first duplicate, which is essentially flawed. But this is a known problem, probably as old as PostgreSQL.
Nowadays the workaround for this is precisely to use a DEFERRABLE constraint.  And there is some irony in that you're looking at it as deficient because it fails to fail, while somehow it's supposed to be the solution to the failure in the first place!

#### Summary of the status quo since PostgreSQL 9.1

- `NOT DEFERRABLE` `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraints are checked **after each row**.
- `DEFERRABLE` constraints set to `IMMEDIATE` (`INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` or via `SET CONSTRAINTS`) are checked **after each statement**.
- `DEFERRABLE` constraints set to `DEFERRED` (`INITIALLY DEFERRED` or via `SET CONSTRAINTS`) are checked **after each transaction**.

Note the special treatment of `UNIQUE` / `PRIMARY KEY` constraints.
Quoting the manual page for `CREATE TABLE`:

> A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately **after every command**.

While it states further down in the *Compatibility* section under [`Non-deferred uniqueness constraints`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-COMPATIBILITY):

> When a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is not deferrable,
> PostgreSQL **checks for uniqueness immediately** whenever a row is
> inserted or modified. The SQL standard says that uniqueness should be
> enforced **only at the end of the statement**; this makes a difference
> when, for example, a single command updates multiple key values. To
> obtain standard-compliant behavior, declare the constraint as
> `DEFERRABLE` but not deferred (i.e., `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`). Be aware
> that this can be significantly slower than immediate uniqueness checking.

Bold emphasis mine.

If you need any `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to reference the column(s), `DEFERRABLE` is not an option because ([per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)):

> The referenced columns must be the columns of a non-deferrable unique
> or primary key constraint in the referenced table.

Answer (score 6):

There may be a slight documentation bug here, but not for the case you're showing.  If you BEGIN a transaction and try the updates one at time, they fail, but if a *single statement* leaves things in a good state, it doesn't complain.  The docs say:

> If a constraint is deferrable, this clause specifies the default time
>   to check the constraint. If the constraint is INITIALLY IMMEDIATE, it
>   is checked after each statement. This is the default. If the
>   constraint is INITIALLY DEFERRED, it is checked only at the end of the
>   transaction.

Which is exactly what seems to be happening.  What is the surprise to me, given the documentation of `DEFERRABLE`, which says in part:

> A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately after
>   every command.

Without the `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE` options, the example update fails, even though the `UPDATE` statement (presumably constituting the "command") leaves things in a good state.  Perhaps the docs should be modified to say that a `NOT DEFERRABLE` constraint is enforced *as each row is modified* by a statement?

Comment: With some delay I [proposed a fix like you suggested to pgsql-docs@postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/519FAC78.7090603@falter.at).