# How to delete record when there is a deadlock of foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables `p` and `u` as following: (PostgreSQL 9.3)

```
CREATE TABLE p
(
  pid integer NOT NULL,
  uid integer,
  CONSTRAINT p_fkey FOREIGN KEY (uid)
      REFERENCES u (uid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);


CREATE TABLE u
(
  uid integer NOT NULL,
  pid integer,
  CONSTRAINT u_fkey FOREIGN KEY (pid)
      REFERENCES p (pid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

In `p` I have:

```
pid        uid
161556     176266
```

in `u` I have

```
uid        pid
176266     161556
```

I want to do:

```
DELETE FROM u WHERE uid=176266;
DELETE FROM p WHERE pid=113116;
```

But I cant.

> ERROR:  update or delete on table "u" violates foreign key constraint
>   "p_fkey" on table "p"
>   DETAIL:  Key (uid)=(176266) is still referenced from table "p".

I understand the error but I don't know what I can do to make the delete.

Suggestions?

Comment: It's not a "deadlock".

Comment: @zerkms  Its defintion of deadlock. can't delete a unless delete b first and cant delete b unless delete a first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete both rows in a single statement:

```
WITH x AS (
   DELETE FROM u WHERE uid = 176266
)
DELETE FROM p WHERE pid = 113116;
```

This works because `IMMEDIATE` constraints is checked at the end of the statement. The statement deletes both rows, and at the end of the statement all integrity constraints are fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Can you explain why this one works? how it avoids the deadlock?

Comment: Is that explanation enough?

Comment: awesome! where did you read about it in PostgreSQL documentation?

Comment: The behaviour of `IMMEDIATE` constraints is explained in the documentation. See for example the documentation for `SET CONSTRAINTS`. The rest was my creativity :^)

Comment: how did you know it set to IMMEDIATE ? I found this to read about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred  but i'm not sure i understand the difference  or moreover why the WITH changes it to after transaction.

Comment: `IMMEDIATE` is the default status for constraints. Your constraints are all `IMMEDIATE`. Another solution would be to change that to `DEFERRABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try update first

```
update p set uid=0 where uid=176266;
delete from  u where uid=176266;
update u set pid=0 where pid=113116;
delete from p where pid=113116;
```

Comment: I'm aware of this option but it's messing up with the data which is something I rather not do. For this solution you also require to have uid=0 in u table.