# One to Many with one table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create one to many relation using one table.
Is this possible?

```
create table user(id int primary key auto_increment not null,                                                                                                                      
created_by int default null                                                                                                                                                        
)ENGINE=INNODB;                                                                                                                                                                    

alter table user add foreign key (created_by) references user(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;                                                                            

insert into user (id) VALUES(1);                                                                                                                                                   
insert into user (id, created_by) VALUES (2,1);
```

Now when I delete user with id=1 the value of created_by automaticaly change to NULL as I expected.

But when I change id of the user with id=1 I get this error

```
mysql> update user set id=2 where id=1;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jrt`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

How can I fix this? Affter this update I want the column created_by to be cascade changed.

Comment: Where did you need such a concept? - just curious.

Comment: I don't need it at all. I am just curious.

Comment: Tim Gee links a forum thread with the exact answer (it's a simple mechanism to prevent infinite loops), make sure you read [the followup](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?136,391782,398085#msg-398085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys aren't meant to be changed, they are meant to be 'identifying'. So user with id 2 is logically a different user with user with id 1. The moment you create a unique user, it's primary key should be the same for the lifetime of that user.

So this is really a design issue. You need to question why you want to change the id for a particular user. It might be that what you want is both a fixed identifying key AND another identifier (which isn't the key and exists solely on the user table) which you can change.

[Updated with more information]
Here's a resource (there are many available online) on the fundamentals of relational database design. http://www.deeptraining.com/litwin/dbdesign/FundamentalsOfRelationalDatabaseDesign.aspx

The relevant section is "Tables, Uniqueness and Keys".

> Fabian Pascal, in his book SQL and Relational Basics, notes that the
>   decision should be based upon the principles of minimality (choose the
>   fewest columns necessary), stability (choose a key that seldom
>   changes), and simplicity/familiarity (choose a key that is both simple
>   and familiar to users).

Personally, I would go further on stability; try to choose a key that never changes. For example, "email" would be a bad choice of key for a user as user's can change their email. If you choose a key, such as an internally generated number or perhaps a unique identifier from the personnel system, then you don't ever have to worry about it changing and migrating this change to other tables.

*Note:* there may be cases where as a "one off" you need to change a primary key. This is best done with a few manual SQL statements (delete the first user and create an identical second user with a different key). It shouldn't be part of the database design though, which the automated nature of a cascaded update implies.

**SEE ALSO:** [When to use "ON UPDATE CASCADE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade)

**ALSO NOTE:** http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?136,391782,391782

Comment: Let's say we have email address instead of id. User want to hange his email and is also primary key of the table like in example above.

Comment: Yes that's bad database design and so there's no automatic way to cascade such a change because you shouldn't do it. I'll update my answer to provide an external resource with clarification.

Comment: @mecio:) Taking email addresses as a primary key is a wrong concept to implement-- a wrong database design.

Comment: Hey, I know it is wrong database desing... But I am trying to implement this for educational purpuse.

Comment: @mecio:) Implementing a wrong database design for educational purpose makes no sense. Do you really want to go in a wrong way?

Comment: @TimGee I see your point :) But I was wondering if this is possible to make this kind of relation between one table. I know it's bad but i need to know if it is possible.

Comment: @Lion I just' play with foreign keys to understand them better. I won't use this database at all.

Comment: OK then my final question..Is it even possible to tell mysql to update   foreign key if i update parent id? We are talking about the above example.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade

Comment: @TimGee I was there..This is quite diffrent concept - we have one table and foreign key that point to the same table.

Comment: I think we are veering off topic from the question you originally asked. You should clarify your original question.

Comment: My question was "is this possible?".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5937/discussion-between-tim-gee-and-mecio)