# Stored Procedure ADO.NET error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

Hello I have a Stored Proc for the Registration Page, but I need ADO.NET to take values from various textboxes.
However, I'm recieving error like this:

"System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type. "

```
public void InsertInfo()
    {
        String empdb = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(empdb);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bridge_Type", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", TextBox2.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", TextBox3.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", TextBox14.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Emptype", dropdown1.SelectedValue));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);

        }

        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InsertInfo();
    }
```

Then I used this format to add values from controls:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters("@EmpID").Value = TextBox1.Text;
```

I'm getting errors on:

```
Its showing errors for these kind of codes by appearing red line under 'Parameters'.

Non-invocable member 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Parameters' cannot be used like a method.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try TextBox1.Text, TextBox is the Control.  The Text property holds the String value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text));
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry those were typo errors. However, I'm getting errors further like this-
Non-invocable member 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Parameters' cannot be used like a method.

When I used code like these_

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters("@EmpID").Value = TextBox1.Text;

Comment: Can you re-post the code without typos?  As it is, you're passing a System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox as an argument, which is not correct because it can't be converted to a native type understood by the SQL provider.  The exception makes perfect sense based on the code you have there.

Comment: The new error is because you are using parentheses, making C# think you want to call a method called 'Parameters' with a string argument.  You want to use brackets [ ]

Comment: Oh Sorry even I couldn't recognize thank you for that.

But this is little tricky for me.. 

Now its coming up with other error- "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32." :(

Comment: Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text), TextBox.Text is a string, the column in your database must be int, so the Int32.Parse(String) method will take a string and create an Int32 for you

Comment: Telling the same after editing:( 
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
try
{
  string empdb = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True";
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("bridge_Type",conn))
    {           
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;           
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID",TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox2.Text);    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob2", TextBox3.Text); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox14.Text); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpType",dropdown1.SelectedValue); 
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
    }
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   string msg = "Insert Error:"+ ex.Message;
   throw new Exception(msg);
}
```

Make sure you are converting to the types same as the Parameter types in your stored proc ( Ex: If the parameter type of EmpID is int, you may need to convert the `TextBox1.Text` value to int. Check for null values also.

Comment: I'm still receiving same error. 
Insert Error:Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

I did use "Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);" But no change in the results.

Comment: How about the EmpTYpe  ? What type it is ?

Comment: This is where the confusion is-

Emptype is a FK in dbo.emp. There's 'Type' which is a PK in dbo.EmpType.

DropDown1 value goes to dbo.EmpType table and then the TypeID(auto-generated) is updated as EmpType in dbo.Emp

Comment: This is where I'd cleared doubt of this concept:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575590/passing-value-to-one-table-and-updating-in-parent-table

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use this format?

```
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@parameter", SqlDBType , size).value = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: But I do not think that is a problem here.

This is where the confusion is- Emptype is a FK in dbo.emp. There's 'Type' which is a PK in dbo.EmpType. DropDown1 value goes to dbo.EmpType table and then the TypeID(auto-generated) is updated as EmpType in dbo.Emp