# C# EF Code First - cascade on update

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade

Is there any way to define for 'cascade on update' but not 'on delete', something like this?

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
               .HasRequired(s => s.Customer)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
               .WillCascadeOnUpdate(true);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706286/why-is-there-no-update-equivalent-to-willcascadeondelete

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't want a foreignkey in a 1 to many relation to update. You are making a relation with that specific object and if the key changes it should mean that the object is different in such a way it requires a new key.