# Reason to use ON UPDATE constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

Is there any reason to use an **`ON UPDATE`** constraint in a database if you will never ever change an ID (better said: primary key field)?

Comment: Check this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade

Comment: Thank you. Seems, that there is no reason (if IDs don't change). The answer with the clubs/bands/concerts is bad database design, I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. Therefore, only if you never change a *referenced field* (as opposed to a primary key), then you can ignore this issue.

Other than that, don't use it if you don't need it.

Side remark: the default behaviour (i.e. if you omit the `ON UPDATE` clause) is to reject any update on the referenced field, preventing you from unknowingly breaking the referential integrity.

Comment: Thanks. I think a *referenced field* should always be a primary key or a part of it in n:m relation tables, right?

Comment: @stofl Yes, I can think of no case where a surrogate key (the most frequent type of primary key) would need to be updated. However, let me refer you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1481611/1446005).