# discussion : updating the primary key value

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns

table : table 1
rec_no --> primary key ( integer )
product
prodlocation

I'll try to do a record shift

`update table1 set rec_no = rec_no - 1` --> works fine

`update table1 set rec_no = rec_no + 1` --> failed, primary key violation

I understand that we should not manipulate the data if it is part of the primary key.

For discussion sake, any idea why the second query failed ? I think it is acceptable if both queries failed.

Comment: Primary key violations usually means that the value you are trying to set already exists in another record.  However, did you run those two queries back to back?

Comment: both queries are seperate function. I just run one query at a time. my data for rec_no are just numbers from 0 to 10. whether it is +1 or -1 the data will still exist.

if both queries failed, it will be easier. only the -1 got success, that puzzled me.

Answer (score 0):

[ON UPDATE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade)

You need to set ON UPDATE CASCADE for those foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE bar
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_foo_bar
FOREIGN KEY (fooid) REFERENCES foo(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Then you simply update the FKs and referring fields will also be updated as part of the transaction:

```
UPDATE foo SET id = id + 1000
```

Note that to alter constraints they need to be dropped.