# How to Reset auto_increment value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, alter

I am not able to reset the auto_increment value even after making changes after referring to other post

I tried :

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 101

ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

or if you haven't already added an id column, also add it

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD INDEX (id);
```

But still not working

Check this :

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE table2 ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> ADD INDEX (id);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from table2;
+----------------+----+
| name           | id |
+----------------+----+
| Abhilash Gupta |  1 |
| John           |  2 |
| Peter          |  3 |
| Clarke         |  4 |
| Virat          |  5 |
+----------------+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE table2 AUTO_INCREMENT=101;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.25 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from table2;
+----------------+----+
| name           | id |
+----------------+----+
| Abhilash Gupta |  1 |
| John           |  2 |
| Peter          |  3 |
| Clarke         |  4 |
| Virat          |  5 |
+----------------+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I want the value of id to start from 101.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The next row you add will have `id = 101`. Changing the auto increment doesn't modify existing rows, you need to use an `UPDATE` statement for that.

Comment: so i have to update all the rows manually ?

Comment: No, you can use the query in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the existing IDs to start from `101`, use:

```
UPDATE table2
SET id = id + 100;
```

The `auto_increment` setting is used for the ID of the next row to be added, it has no effect on existing rows.

Comment: In addition, if `id` is referenced as a foreign key from other tables, you may need to first set [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade) to ensure that the referential integrity is maintained

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link for reference to [AUTO INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Now what you are doing is i think correct, but the changes are not reflected because you did not try to enter a new row to the database. Alter command changes the AUTO INCREMENTS value but that will only be reflected in the next insert to the database. It will not affect the data that is already present in the TABLE. Try entering a new row to the DB and check if the ID Value changes.
If not then post the output after entering that row.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be written

```
cur.execute('''ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=0''')
```

Comment: Using all capitals is considered shouting. It is rude. I have edited your answer to fix this, but in the future please make sure to avoid that and instead use proper capitalization.