# Is it possible to implement self referencing foreign key with update cascade in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [SomeTable](
                         [Id] int NOT NULL
                        ,[SomeColumn] varchar(50) NULL
                        ,[ParentId] int NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_SomeTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

ALTER TABLE [SomeTable]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT 
     [FK_SomeTable_SomeTable] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId])
     REFERENCES [SomeTable] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [SomeTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_SomeTable_SomeTable]
```

Sql Server does not allow me to put `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Is there any way to get that if i update `Id` column, all child rows `ParentId` get updated too?

Comment: I don't think you can workaround that limitation except for writing a trigger that does this for you  (using a recursive query)

Comment: Generally speaking, the primary key columns should be immutable. In this particular case, even more. The only way to work around your problem is to remove the FK declaration altogether and implement the RI with code (read: triggers).

Comment: There's somewhat of a related conversation here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481476/when-to-use-on-update-cascade