# postgres how to reset or update index(sequence) of table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-sequence

i deleted 2000 row in my table and then i inserted same 2000 records but their index(id auto increment field) starting from 2001,
now i want to update those index 2001 - 4000 to 1-2000

Comment: a simple update won't do the work?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Why do you want to renumber? Those id's doesn't mean anything to you anyway.

Comment: reset the sequence. som google research will deliver you the answer.

Comment: i've dont that but reset sequence didn't work for existing data(ids) @RemigiusStalder

Comment: because here two tables are compared in bases of their ids(unfortunately) so if by mistake one table's id get override we lose the track... @jarlh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To update your id run the following command.

`UPDATE table SET id = id - 2000;`

This will update the id of records in your table and then you need update the table's sequence

`ALTER SEQUENCE table_id_seq RESTART WITH 2001;`

This will allow you to insert the data with the id **2001**

Another way, delete all the records from the table and update the sequence of the table and reinsert the data.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it is not working for the record referenced from other table!! do you have any idea about?!!

Comment: @user3321823, you can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on the foreign-key of referenced table. This will update the reference whenever you update the referenced table as well. Reference : [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) and [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1481524)