# On Update Cascade not changing value of foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables being:

'bin' and 'missedbin' ,missed bin contains a foreign key or the primay key 'binID' from bin. I have set the foreign key to cascade on update & delete.

However, when a value is inserted into bin the foreign key is not updated within the missedbin table and remains null. Have I done something incorrectly?

EDIT:
missedbin table:

[image: missedbin]
bin table:

[image: bin]

I have 2 insert statements running in asp:

`cmd.CommandText = "insert into mydb1.bin values(null,'" + binType + "','" + binColour + "','" + personIDdata + "')";`

`cmd.CommandText = "insert into mydb1.missedbin values (null, '" + personIDdata + "','" + dateFound + "', null)";`

Comment: Could you provide the CREATE TABLE SQL and the INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE query?

Comment: Read this answer to clarify this feature: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1481528/1545088

Comment: @Sebastian that enough details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key does not work that way. You have to provide the correct binID when inserting into missedBin (always). You can use LAST_INSERT_ID(). Only if you later change bin.binID, then the binID in missedBin will change as well

```
INSERT INTO bin () VALUES () ...
INSERT INTO missedbin (binID, ...) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...)
```

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not sure I understand. What is the point of foreign keys if they don't have the same values of primary keys always?

Comment: Well, how should Mysql know which rows shall be connected? You always have to set the initial keys yourself. The foreign key can only support you, when you UPDATE or DELETE a row